# Seeding Planets with Humans, Explanation

Tags: history, andromeda

In Episode 18 of Season 3 "Deep Midnight's Voice" The crew go to an unnamed planet in search of a lost spaceship.

When detailing the planet it is mentioned that Humans were seeded on the planet 10,000 years ago to start a colony, but the communication broke down and so the Humans evolved there for 10,000 years alone and believe they are alone in the universe and their technology is like Earth 90's technology.

My question is about the "seeding" of the Humans 10,000 years ago, it is mentioned that another alien race did this seeding and I want to know where I can get some information about this.

Specifically, is this a common thing? Is that why there are so many Humans on so many planets? Was it done with consent? Or were Humans simply abducted and then seeded on this planet? If so, was this done to other alien races?

I know this is a lot of questions, but they are all tied to the same answer/source or explanation. I understand that the whole story of Andromeda is loosely based on some works by Gene Roddenberry so I hope that there is more on this fact then just a phrase uttered in an episode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [timeline](http://www.personal.utulsa.edu/~marc-carlson/misc/andrrtime.htm) on the (now defunct) "All Systems University" website, the Slipstream was discovered in 5038BC. By 4926BC General Huascar nax Yoweri had led a campaign of conquest across the Six Galaxies culminating in the foundation of the Vedran Empire. It is during this period that Earth was likely discovered and catalogued (but not directly contacted).

Humanity was officially 'first contacted' by the Perseids in 2129AD with Earth becoming a full member of the [Systems Commonwealth](http://andromeda.wikia.com/wiki/Systems_Commonwealth) in 2159AD.

The majority of the events that take place in the TV series Andromeda happen between the years 5161-5165AD concluding with the destruction of Earth, the defeat of 'The Abyss' and Tarn-Vedra rejoining the Universe.

Any seeding of humans would therefore have taken place at the very height of the Vedran Empire, potentially for the purposes of study or in an attempt to breed a slave-race.

Ultimately humans end up being approximately 25% of the galactic population due to our prolific breeding and desire to spread as widely as possible so it's not unsurprising that a race like the Vedrans (who were paranoid about being outnumbered in their own empire) would want to study and emulate certain of our characteristics.

Comment: So, 10,000 years ago would be just around the time that slipstream was discovered, and about 5000 BC - So probably done without consent. Thanks for the answer, and the links!

Comment: I don't think you can assume it was without consent of the individuals per se. Certainly from an ethical perspective transplanting individuals from a pre-industrial (let alone pre-contact) civilisation would seem to be questionable given that the individuals would lack understanding of the consequences of their actions, both to them personally but also to those left back on the original planet.